# Derive a contradiction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

1) Jones: "Most of Nixon's assertions are false"

2) Nixon: "All Jones' assertions are true"

Suppose all the Nixon's assertions are evenly split into true and false assertions except (2).

Suppose Nixon (2) is true. Then most of Nixon's assertions are true. It follows that (1) is true, that is most of Nixon's assertions are false. Contradiction.

Suppose (2) is false. Then most of Nixon's assertions are false and there exists Jones' assertion that is not true and so (1) is either false or true.

Suppose (1) is false, ($\forall$ Nixon's assertions $x, x$ is true), but most of Nixon's assertions are false. Contradiction.

Suppose (1) is true, hence Most of Nixon's assertions are false and it's indeed the case.

How to derive a contradiction in the last supposition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, there really is no contradiction if 1) is true and 2) is false ... as long as Jones makes at least one assertion other than 1) that is false.

For in that case, it is not true that all of Jones' assertions are true, and hence 2) is indeed false, while most of Nixon's assertions are false, and hence 1) is indeed true.

If 1) is the only assertion that Jones makes ... or if Jones makes other asssertions but they are all true, then you would have a contradiction. But that is not given.

Comment: I get it now. I suppose that (2) is false and (1) is true, meaning that it is not the case that all Jones' assertions are true. But we only have one Jones' assertion which is true, so all Jones' assertions are true.

Comment: @super.t Right ... *if* 1) is the *only* assertion by Jones, then there is a contradiction ... it's just that the problem statement says nothing to that effect. I mean, they give 2) as the only explicit assertion made by Nixon, but then point out that he may be making several other assertions. So why not Jones?